# Redeploying an early deployment using Visual Studio Online with Git For continuous delivery to Azure

Tags: git, azure, visual-studio-2013, azure-devops

I'm setting up continuous delivery to Azure using Visual Studio Online with Git repository for a website using a free Azure trial account in visual studio 2013. In Azure portal, all successful deployments are listed under the Deployments tab for that website.

But when I want to redeploy an earlier deployment, I get following error :

**"Cannot redeploy a build that was a gated check-in, private build, batched multiple requests, or with a source get version which is not a changeset".**

The items shown in deployment history looks like this:

Individual Continuous Integration - *****deploytest1_CD_20140718.1 - View Log

**ID:N/A**          **author:N/A**          deployed by:*****deploytest2

You can see the ID and author is N/A. Not sure if this is a known issue.

Is there any configuration I have to set to get the Id's and author for each deployment in the build definition?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might be expected behavior. Are there multiple changesets in the push to the server? For example, I commit 1, 2, and 3 locally, then push to VSO which would kick off the CI build. That would then fall under the batched multiple requests header.